# Whre's the line between puzzling and game dev?

Tags: discussion

related: [Should languages related to programming and writing code be on-topic?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14197/91320)

Since our site is about the *creation* and solving of puzzles, i was thinking we will get some problems, like "How to generate a maze?". Some of these questions will be better suited here, and some will be better suited at GameDev StackExchange. Where do we draw the line?

Answer (score 3):

What is on-topic on GameDev.SE is irrelevant, we just need to decide where the  line is here. I say questions about general algorithms for solving puzzles are on-topic; questions about a specific implementation of said algorithm is not. General questions about how best to model a game are on the border but I'd say on-topic (we'll see, when we get some, whether the community agrees or closes them), but again questions about a specific implementation in a language are off-topic.

Comment: Ok, but let's remind people to migrate such questions to/from GameDev StackExchange, and tell the OP if they're on-topic there.